# excel UsedRange is not shown properly when columns are hidden

Tags: excel, excel-2007, office-interop, excel-2010, vba

When I hide a columns ( lets say N )  and then if I find the used range using activesheet.usedrange function then it does not give me correct used range.
However when I hide one row and use the above function it gives correct used range.

To try this Please hide one column lets say N. And then press ctrl + END on the keyboard , you will see the focus goes to cell A1. where as if you hide one row ( on a new sheet ) lets say 10th row and press ctrl + end then it will take you to 9th row.
Alternatively you can check the UsedRange by using VBA code or you try this by writing the c# addin , and see the contents of UsedRange on the above two scenarios.

Why this is so ?

Comment: Can you give an explicit example?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `usedrange`?

Comment: @SiddharthRout : I want to extract the group of hidden/invisible row and columns on sheet when there are groupes of row/columns on the sheet. So for that if I run LINQ queriy on Worksheet.Rows/columns to fetch the hidden rows/columns, logic hangs. For that purpose when I tried to fetch the hidden rows/columns on UsedRange , the logic works for Rows but BREAKS in case COLUMNS because as I mentioned above UsedRange is not returned correctly when columns are HIDDEN.

Comment: Would a simple VBA code to find the hidden Rows and Columns work for you?

Comment: It will be great if you share that with me I will convert that into C# stuff , but please check it performance in case when it finds the hidden rows on the sheet , that shold not be time consuming.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour of the `UsedRange` property of a Worksheet appears to be inconsistent.

Hiding a column beyond the `UsedRange` does not cause the property to change.

Hiding a row beyond the `UsedRange` **does** cause the property to extend as far as the hidden row.

There is no further mention of this in the [specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840732.aspx).